# Windows Phone 8 app publishing tool from the cli?

Tags: windows-phone-8, jenkins, continuous-integration, publishing, windows-store

I've been researching if it's possible to integrate Android, iOS and Windows Phone 8 in a buildscript for Jenkins. The main goal is if there is a release in a specified branch in the given VCS, that it'll publish them to their responsible store. At the moment I've a way to publish Android and iOS, but it seems that there is nothing for Windows Phone 8.

The question is:

> Is there a command-line based application that is able to publish Windows Phone 8 apps to the Windows Store?

If there is a way to integrate with a API or simply by doing some POST/GET requests, I would like to know as well. At the moment I'm researching that part.

The part of building and signing the APK's, APPX's and IPA's is already taken care off.

- For iOS I'm able to use FastLane(Deliver) or
  Nomadcli(Shenzhen);
- For Android I'm able to use a Jenkins plugin(Google Play Publisher) or integrating with the API (there are various command-line based applications out there);

I would really appriciate if you can leave a answer! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API for the Windows Store available (yet) that would allow you to do this.